# Is a readonly field in VB.NET thread safe?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Is a readonly field in VB.NET thread safe? For example, see the code below:

```
Class Customer
  ReadOnly Name As String

  ReadOnly ZIP As Integer = 98112

  Sub New(ByVal Name As String)

    Me.Name = Name

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: By `field` do you mean a variable or a property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if nobody can write it, everyone is synced on its value.

Besides, you could make this integer constant (or shared readonly)

Comment: you are helpful

Comment: I would strongly recommend making it constant, as this documents that A) ZIP will not change within the constructor and B) that all customers have the same ZIP.  B is achievable without A by making it shared.